# Am I taking value objects too far (DDD)

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

*EDIT:
For clarity, this question is related to DDD, which has a concept called Value Objects, these are not Value Types, they are a way of building objects in such a way that the contents make up the identity, I was trying to understand how far these concepts should apply (From Comments it seems they should not seep outside domain). This question may look odd for people not familiar with DDD but to be clear it is about a very specific mechanism for creating objects NOT creating value types.*

Consider the following sample code, which has two Value Objects:

```
public class SqlServerConnectionSettings
{
    public string DatabaseName { get; set; }

    public string ServerName { get; set; }

    public SqlServerCredentials Credentials { get; private set; }

    public SqlServerConnectionSettings(SqlServerCredentials credentials)
    {
        Credentials = credentials;
    }

    public string AsConnectionString()
    {
        //Snip
    }
}

public class SqlServerCredentials
{
    public string Username { get; private set; }

    public string Password { get; private set; }

    public bool UseIntegratedSecurity { get; private set; }

    public SqlServerCredentials(string username = "", string password = "", bool useIntegratedSecurity = true)
    {
        Username = username;
        Password = password;
        UseIntegratedSecurity = useIntegratedSecurity;
    }

    public string AsConnectionStringCredentials()
    {
       //Snip
    }
}
```

Rather than have distinct params for Username, Password, UseIntegratedSecurity I have created a value object to hold them. My question is, Is this taking the concept too far, have I misunderstood the point value objects have been designed for?

Comment: Looks like a good approach. The credentials are a separate entity from the connection settings and thus can be made into their own class. This allows you to add more options to the `SqlServerCredentials` in the future without exposing the underlying mechanics of the class.

Comment: Your question is quite subjective. But if it seems right to you, then it's probably right. Please correct the spelling of **integrated**.

Comment: @KlausByskovHoffmann It's not a question of which one 'seems' right. There are a lot of people doing DDD and I would like guidance on when a value object is necessary vs superfluous. Fixed the spelling.

Comment: I would rather call that infrastructure and not part of the domain.

Comment: @jgauffin I agree and I wouldn't put too much in the infastructure that is specific to the domain but I do find there are "Mini Domains" in infrastructure.

Comment: Your domain should be persistant ignorant. The connection details is NEVER part of a DDD domain. It's not a value object or an entity. It's just infrastucture outside the domain.

Comment: @jgauffin They are not part of the domain in a sense, they are hidden behind a persistence layer, I thought it might make sense to apply some DDD concepts to my infrastructure, like value objects. Do you think this could come back to bite me? I started with a single connectionBuilder object which was much smaller as it had no value objects, this is the essence of why I asked the question. If I can get the question open again id be interested in and answer?

Comment: Yes. You are trying to solve a non-existant problem. Simply create a SQLServerConnectionFactory which produces connections. The only information it would require is the name of the connection string in app/web.config. Use `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` to load it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good to me. You group items which belong together into cohesive units, what could be wrong about that?

Comment: My concern, I think, is maintenance. But on the other hand I suppose any validation on the SqlServerCredentials or its attributes would be packaged nicely into its own VO.

Comment: Maintenance is much more helped by clear, purposeful code rather than by compactness. So in my opinion, your approach is very maintainable.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your context.

- If you define `SqlServerCredentials` as an Entity, yes, you're going too far :

> "An entity is an object that is not defined by its attributes, but rather by a thread of continuity and its identity."

- If you define `SqlServerCredentials` as a Value Object, you're right (don't forget that it should be **immutable** !):

> "A value object is an object that contains attributes but has no conceptual identity. They should be treated as immutable."

- If you define `SqlServerCredentials` as an Aggregate, you're right, too :

> A n aggregate is a collection of objects that are bound together by a root entity, otherwise known as an aggregate root. The aggregate root guarantees the consistency of changes being made within the aggregate by forbidding external objects from holding references to its members.

In conclusion, in a DDD way, if you're not considering `SqlServerCredentials` as an entity, it's ok. But it's all about context.